# Trying to use keylset and keylget in Tcl

Tags: tcl

When I use tcl code like this its working fine

```
keylset mylist LastName Hello FirstName World
puts [keylget mylist LastName]
puts [keylget mylist FirstName]
```

Output:
Hello
World

Now if I want to store those key and value pair in a variable then run it I am getting an error

```
set mylist2 {LastName Hello FirstName World}
keylset mylist $mylist2
puts [keylget mylist LastName]
```

i am getting an error - i know i am using wrong args for keylset but i dont know what else i can do.

Comment: For those playing along at home, the two commands in question are part of the TclX package, and aren't in base Tcl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to expand that list of arguments to `keylset`, given that it all works with direct arguments:

```
keylset mylist {*}$mylist2
```

(In ancient versions of Tcl, you'd use `eval keylset mylist $mylist2` instead, but that's not recommended as it has potential evaluation hazards, and the non-hazardous version, `eval [linsert $mylist2 0 keylset mylist]`, is truly horrible. This was a big language change from 8.4 to 8.5, and basically made `eval` nearly obsolete overnight.)